# Google policies clarification about donation and advertisement

Tags: android

I was about to publish my first app and I added a url link on my splash screen. will that violate any policy?

And about the donation button, can I add it to my application? I have been searching for answer and can't find a reliable one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is against that you are advertise your other apps like more apps is against in google documentation but many people doing that for advertising other app.

As well if you are using donation button only for inapp purchase than its not against google policy.

And you are adding link in any screen means you are opening your website or something but make sure that link should be reliable i mean if your link is for register in the Batting web site than that my affect your app but simply open an link in browser that's not violating google policy you can upload it on playstore without worry.

Comment: The link is just a facebook page, is that fine? it is just under my logo after they opened my app.

Comment: that's not an problem you can open your fb business page or anything like that :)

Comment: I see, that's great! Thank you very much Ajay :)

Comment: pleasure man ready to help Happy Coding :) if your confusion is resolved accept my answer so this question is removed from unanswered list.

Comment: Well I really need a guide about In App Billing, could you guide me? Can we chat or something?

Comment: yes of course start chat because i don't know how to start chat in stack overflow or well you can refer this http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/implement-in-app-purchase-version-3

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1009240/How-to-Implement-Android-In-App-Purchases